# Finding the prove of the inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A=(a_{ij})_{n×n} $ a matrix and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A$, then $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\lambda_i|^{2} \le \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|^{2} $$

I can prove that $|\lambda|\le \sum_{j=1} |a_{kj}| $ for some $1\le k \le n $.

But what's next?

Also, it is given that given that the equality is possible iff the matrix is unitarily diagonalizable. Is that means towards tha symmetric matrices?

Comment: Look at $A^{\ast}A$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer♦ thanks for the hints , but one question, it proves the equality. So,when do the strict inequality will happen ? Is there any example possible for strictly inequality case?

Comment: @gabrimev I asked for strict inequality case.

Comment: @Alearner Strict inequality occurs if and only if $AA^* \neq A^*A$

Comment: @Alearner It is true. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $M = UAU^*$ is upper triangular, then the diagonal entries of $M$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\sum_{i,j}|m_{ij}|^2 = \sum_{i} |\lambda_i|^2$.

---

If we unitarily upper triangularize $A$ as I suggest above, note that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\lambda_i|^{2} < \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|^{2} \iff\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} |m_{ii}|^{2} \le \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^j|m_{ij}|^{2} \iff\\
\text{There exists a pair } i<j \text{ such that } m_{ij} \neq 0.
$$
With this, we can see that the following are equivalent:

- Strict inequality holds
- *There exists* a unitary $U$ for which $UAU^*$ is upper triangular but not diagonal
- *For every* unitary $U$, $UAU^*$ fails to be diagonal.

Comment: I have already got that. I am still very interested to know how the strict inequality will happen? **Source of this question: Linear Algebra by Fuzhen Zhang**

Comment: @Alearner As I said in my comment, strict inequality occurs if and only if $AA^* \neq A^*A$, which (by the "spectral theorem") is equivalent to the condition that $A$ fails to be unitarily diagonalizable

Comment: Will you prove the strict inequality part, please?

Comment: @Alearner See my latest edit

Comment: @Alearner I have not explicitly mentioned it, but I have assumed from your comments that you are comfortable with the idea that for every matrix, there exists an upper-triangularizing unitary matrix, i.e. [Schur's triangularization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition).

Comment: it's ok. I got it now. Thanks!! I just miscalculated whenever I transpose the upper triangular matrix,,, I take the result matrix as upper triangular matrix again and again.. Sorry , for misunderstanding you!!